# if it has footer.text it reacts, but I want it to do the opposite

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

what it does is add a reaction `:pray:` when an embed has `footer.text`, but I don't want that, I want it to react when it doesn't have a `footer.text`

```
if(message.embeds.length >= 0) 
    // Check if the Message has embed or not
    {
      let embed = message.embeds
      // console.log(embed) just a console.log
      for(let i = 0; i < embed.length; i++)
      // Loop it since in v13 you can send multiple embed in single message
      {
        if (!embed[i] || !embed[i].footer || embed[i].footer.text === null) return;
        // check each embed if it has footer.text or not, if it doesnt then do nothing
        {
          setTimeout(function(){
            message.react(':pray:')
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to switch your conditions like so:

```js
if (embed[i] || embed[i].footer || embed[i].footer.text !== null) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        message.react('')
    }, 1000);
}
```

Where [`!==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality)  represents `Strict Inequality` so what you are actually doing is checking the following conditions

- If there is an embed to the message
- If that embed object has a footer
- If the content of the footer is not empty

Further since all of these conditions are necessary I would suggest using [`Logical AND (&&)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) operator which only returns true if the checks of all operands are fulfilled, so your code would look something like this:

```js
if (embed[i] && embed[i].footer && embed[i].footer.text !== null) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        message.react('')
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I used the second one but I had to add `return;` for it to work
`if (embed[i] && embed[i].footer && embed[i].footer.text !== null) return;`